# Running Vagrant on Apple Silicon (M2) with v.gui=false

Tags: apple-silicon, virtualization, vmware, macos

#### Background

I've recently upgraded from an Intel MBP to an M2 MBP, so I had to update my Vagrant. Reading around led me to first download the latest [VMware Fusion Tech Preview](https://blogs.vmware.com/teamfusion/2023/07/vmware-fusion-2023-tech-preview.html), then update my Vagrant installation. I chose to uninstall existing Vagrant stuff, & start from scratch...

```
brew install --cask vagrant
brew install --cask vagrant-vmware-utility
brew install --cask vagrant-manager
vagrant plugin install vagrant-share
vagrant plugin install vagrant-vmware-desktop
```

I started with `Vagrantfile`...

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Variables
MEMORY              = 4096
CPUS                = 1
VM_IP               = "192.168.98.99"

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

    config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-20.04-arm64"

    config.vm.provider "vmware_desktop" do |v|
        v.memory = MEMORY
        v.cpus   = CPUS
    end

    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: VM_IP

end
```

I run `vagrant up` & get...

```
An error occurred while executing `vmrun`, a utility for controlling
VMware machines.
```

Searching for answers to that, I found [this](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant-vmware-desktop/issues/53#issuecomment-1550458042) & [this](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/vagrant-up-fails-on-macos-m1-w-wmware/44541), both saying I had to set `v.gui = true` in my `Vagrantfile`. That works, but it requires having VMware Fusion running, which opens a window that must remain open for the life of the VM session.

#### Question

Is there any way to run Vagrant without having a VMware Fusion GUI (with `v.gui = false`)?

Comment: Did you solve it? I can't run vagrant on my Mac M1

Comment: @Atais no, but VMware Fusion is not a fully released product, so I shall be revisiting it shortly.